# How do I create a number of chars that are automatically given a name based on a int?

Tags: java, string

I'm currently creating a program and needs a way to convert each letter of a string to a char.  The number of letters in the string is variable, so I'm using

```
s.length()
```

to create an int that has the number of chars that I need to make.  My question is how do I extract the letters from each point in the string and input them into chars which are automatically named?  e.g.

```
char zero = s.charat(0)
char one = s.charat(1)
etc...
```

Comment: you can't. you'll have to do it by hand it you want them named.

Comment: The way you are approaching this problem is not how you should do this. You can't create variables at runtime. Use loops and arrays or lists to do what you need to do.

Comment: Why would you want to? What are you going to do with these named variables?

Comment: What about using [`String#toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and you just access using `charArray[index]`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do thing what you've done in your example. You'll have to do it by hand or make some kind of List, for example ArrayList. If so, do loop and check if it's bigger than `int i` and then add value to that list. The other (and probably easier) way would be to use `String.toCharArray` and you would be able to do something like `charArray[char number]` then.

Example:

```
String s = "Wesley Luh";
char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
System.out.println("" + ca[0] + ca[1] + ca[2]); // would result in Wes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) to obtain the `char[]` from the `String` you're working with. Then, access to the elements of the `char[]` by using something like `charArray[index]`.

```
String yourString = "hello world";
char[] charArray = yourString.toCharArray();
int index = 4;
System.out.println(charArray[index]); //prints 'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them into an arraylist of Characters and access them by index instead of naming the individual variables.